# Retrieving the COM class factory for component error while generating word document

Tags: asp.net, com, ms-word

I am trying to edit a word document from VB.NET using for the most part this code:

**How to automate Word from Visual Basic .NET to create a new document**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383

It works fine on my machine but when i publish to the server i get the following error.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80070005.
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80070005.

The actual error happens when i try to just create a word application object

```
 Dim oWord As New Word.Application
```

Using Visual Studio 2008 and VB.NET 3.5. I made a reference to the "Microsoft Word 10.0 Object Library" and i see Interop.Word.dll file in the bin directory.

Using MS Office 2003 on development machine and Windows Server 2003

Still fairly new to .NET and don't have much knowledge about window server, but "UnauthorizedAccessException" sounds like a permission issue. I'm wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on what i might need to do to give my little application access to use word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It definitely sounds like a permissions problem. Are you running your code in a windows service? The service normally runs as Local System, which may not have permission to access the Word object model. Additionally, if word is already running using the credentials of some other user then your program may not be able to access it via COM using different credentials. The office applications tend to be single instance which seems to exacerbate this problem.

Comment: Interesting enough when i logged into the system and ran Word it ran the installer. I guess no one ran word before on this user. It didn't solve my problem but i'm wondering even w/o the permission issue if that would have stopped it from working. 

No my code is a Web Application. While this is a small rarely used app i never considered what would happen if two people tried to run it at the same time.Thanks for that input.

Is there a way to see if some one other is accessing the COM object? I'm pretty sure nothing else is but i wouldn't even know where to check that.

Comment: The Web application is running as what user? In IIS 7 for instance, the application pool will run as local system which will probably have the same problem.

Comment: Again excuse my ignorance but is "Network Service" what you are talking about? It's the identity the application pool is set to use.

Comment: yes, there are two well know userids that services commonly run as. Local system is a low privileged userid that is normally used by services that do not provide services to the network. Network service is used by services that do

Comment: You could try to configure the application pool to use your credentials instead

Comment: I added <identity impersonate="true"/> to the webconfig and then added myself to the MS Word Document DCOM and i get the same 80080005 error i mentioned below. I found the 'Application ID' in DCOM for Word Application ID is {00020906-00000-0000-C000-000000000046} but the error i'm getting says  CLSID 000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 i wonder if that is relevant. Thank you again for your help i've learned a lot even if my problem is still there. :D

Comment: I logged into the server as myself, ran the web app, and it popped up some weird windows live thing and when i hit 'continue' it actually did launch word but gave me the ASP.NET error "The Add method or property is not available because the license to use this application has expired". Haha the office on the server has never been activated... and i just realized i have word 2002 (MS 10) and the server has 2003 (MS 11).... i'll look into both those issues.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Word is running through a Windows Service under a service account.

The problem was that the Desktop folder didn't exist in `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile` (or in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile`).

Adding it resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have a permission issue in DCOM. Try editing the Word permissions in DCOM config.

Comment: Found a few people referencing http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/03/02/589.aspx but its for excel. Didn't help, the error is the same but the error number did change changed to:  80080005.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException instead of System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be what you are experiencing.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/006cbbac-101a-40ea-ae16-d59a7a2da8b1

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and the problem area I found was **"security configuration for Microsoft Word in DCOM".** On the following link you can find a step by step guide to know how to config components in DCOM, repeate these steps for WORD, and your problem will be solved.

**http://www.biocompsystems.com/_public/DCOMConfigurationStepbyStepForXP.doc**

Thanks,
Sushil Jinder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 2008 R2.  Ended up using this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/65a355ce-49c1-47f1-8c12-d9cf5f23c53e

and then changing the impersonation identity user in web.config to another user to solve it.

I'm sure there is a combination of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Start -> Run** 
type **regedit -32** and press enter key.

-- *Registry Editor* will get open.

Go To registry **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application** 

Select **Word.Application** and set full permission to below users:-

Administrator, Administrators, Local Service, System, Service, Interactive  and Users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while generating word document. The issue i solved by checking the task manager, and by ending the currently running process WINWORD.EXEs and then executed my code again. The issue gone.