# Error Retrieving the COM class factory for component

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I have a web service which loads a 32-bit COM component. I am running this web service with IIS server in my local machine.

When I load the the test page from Visual Studio it succeeds, on the other hand, while loading it using IIS, it display following error

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component XXX failed due to the following error: 80070005.
```

I tried changing the webservice's platform to x86 from Any CPU but that dint help. I am running this on Windows Server 2008 R2 - 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable the 32-bit Applications from the Application Pools settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on that COM. It may be that when you're running tests from VS, you're running as you (admin), while the user running the website's app-pool is totally different. That user needs to be added read+execute (or, activate, whatever) permissions for "local".

Maybe also see this: [Retrieving the COM class factory for component error while generating word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190600/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-error-while-generating-word-docum)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run directly from the explorer (under current user privilege) it's working fine. On the other hand, if I execute from IIS, it's showing this error

Comment: That's why I'm telling you to check permissions for acivating and executing that COM app for the user that is running the app pool for your website.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I am new to IIS and webservices. When Right-Click and browse the webservice, it will display a default page with the available public methods. Under which credentials the service will be running? Will it be running with the current logged-in user credentials? How to check this otherwise?

Comment: Application pool name used by a website will be displayed within properties of that website. Then, once you find that name, go to the folder labeled "Application Pools" (still within IIS manager), and find that app-pool, open its properties, and you'll see which user account is used to run it. Then, find your COM+ app (separate config manager in admin tools folder), open its properties, and set its activation and execute permissions for local execution to that user (I forgot details, but I was trying to use words that you'll likely see in those config windows).

Comment: It's just a normal COM component and was imported to the WebService code and launching it from there. So there's not COM+ configuration for it.

Comment: If it's a COM+ app, it's got to be listed in admin tools > component services > COM+ applications; and the config for it should be there. The "XXX" in your message should be its name. See if it's listed there.

Comment: I think the issue got resolved by fixing - permissions in C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\ folder. Anyway yet to finalize it

Comment: This workaround went through. Adding permission to the config folder helped to load the component. But I am not sure how it's related to this. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Sarat, this cannot be right. The "Enable 32-bit Applications" under Application Pools Defaults is not for running 32-bit applications or to solve your problem. It is there to enforce running 32-bit applications UNDER 32-bit processes only, which is not necessary in this case. Most 32-bit applications run fine on 64-bit processes. That's why you can run MS Office 2010 (which is still a 32-bit application) on Windows 7 64-bit machines.

You must have other settings tried and true after nearly a full year answering the original problem.