# Error : Interop.word.dll error

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop

I have used Microsoft.office.interop.word dll to view word document and it is working fine on code level debugging 
but after publishing my project on the same machine i am getting this exception 
while creating the dll object

> retrieving the COM class factory for component wit CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-00000000046} failed due to the following
>   error : 80070005

Didn't find any solutions yet on web .. kindly help me

Comment: `80070005` is the access denied error.

Comment: Rahul can u please guide me how to solve this ..!! i have done almost everything to grand permission to dll , i have created new users as well and check the allow all field .. but still receiving the same

Comment: after pulishing your project you are putting it on server or on different machine.

Comment: no .. i am publishing it on my machine , IIS server locally

Comment: i read somewhere that office must be installed on the server where i have to publish , but i am publishing it on my machine

Comment: that's why i m asking for you that where you putting your project,,because i knew this thing that if you put your project on server then make sure that office must be install there,,but u r saying that everything is fine and u r put it locally on `IIS`..

Comment: yes ...!! please tell me any solution if you know any

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491123/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-word-in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190600/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-error-while-generating-word-docum

Comment: It looks like a permission/rights issue to me.

Comment: dotnetsoldier .. i know that .. please provide me with some solution

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Good question +1 for that...

Comment: @JohnSaunders I agree with your point, but he is probably working on an older app or fixing some code.

Comment: @owais or it could as easily been a new application. It doesn't really matter. It's _still_ a horrible idea. It is meant for desktop apps, which are not multithreaded. ASP.NET runs each request on a different thread, which can be a disaster.

Comment: @owais I learned this the hard way when I was told to fix the memory leak in an app. Turns out no memory leak. C runtime library was not reentrant. As soon as "malloc" was run on a second thread, the entire heap was corrupted. From then on it was a exception for every reference to the heap. Of course then the exception was ignored  which is a separate thing to never do.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for sharing your experience,I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Goto Start > Run > dcomcnfg 64
2. Console Root > Component Services > My Computer > DCOM Config
3. Choose Details View for easy navigation.
4. Find Excel and Word
5. Right click > Properties
6. On the security tab: Select Customize under Launch and Activation Permissions and click Edit…
7. Add the account under which the site is running (eg: Network Service) and assign Local Launch & Local Activation permissions and Also Add `IIS_IUSRS` and give full permissions.

**Snapshots**
*Step 2*
[image]
*Step 3*
[image]
*Step 4*
[image]

**P.S:** Adapted and modified from [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491123/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-word-in)